# Find out user role name by user id in identity framework

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am trying to figure out how to find user role name in identity framework . I am using `ASPNETUSERS , ASPNETUSERROLE & ASPNETROLE`.

Answer (score 1):

first of all find out userrole in aspnetusers table and then find userrole name in aspnetroles

Find logged in userID -- You can skip this if you know your userID

```
var loggedUser = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
```

Find logged in user roleID

```
var aspnetuserole = db.AspNetUserRoles.Find(loggedUser);
```

Find RoleName

```
var roleName = db.AspNetRoles.Find(aspnetuserole.roleID);
```